# 403 for all protected routes using spring security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I started a new spring 3.0.2 project with spring security and I'm trying to create a register/login rest API for now as I am a begineer.
I managed to get a this working but after when my user is authentified I have a 3rd controller that will display information. However, I am always getting 403 response.
I am using the JWT token library to manage request here are some piece of code of my project.

my configuration for filtering request as you can only 2 endpoints are free to visit and I want all the rest to be locked to authentificated users only.

```
    private final Filter tokenAuthentificationFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authentificationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf()
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**", "/api/v1/test-controller")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authentificationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(tokenAuthentificationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
```

if I'm not connected the /api/v1/auth and /test-controller works correctly but when I'm connected I have a "protected" endpoint /protected and it returns 403
below it's my tokenAuthentificationFilter class

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TokenAuthentificationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtService jwtService;

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String authToken;
        String userEmail;
        if(authorizationHeader == null || !authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer")){
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        authToken = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
        userEmail = jwtService.extractEmail(authToken);// TODO extract userEmail from JWT Token;
        if(userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
            if(jwtService.isTokenValid(authToken, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                authenticationToken.setDetails(
                        new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
                );
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

No log error in my console

Answer (score 0):

code seems fine to me but this might not be the one causing problem, try putting in a few print statements inside your code. ***See the flow of requests from filters to endpoint***. Then try hitting the ***protected endpoint***, it should give you an idea where's the request is blocked. Then try to work from there, that's how i solved most of spring security problems.